# Invalid CSRF Token - error in chrome browser

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working on a web application built using Spring framework. I am getting `Invalid CSRF Token` error. I see this behavior only in Chrome browser. Following are the steps followed:

1. Login to the application by providing userName and password
2. Click on Logout button to logout. The user will be re-directed to the login page
3. Then, in the login page again try to login. I am getting the below error

`Invalid CSRF Token 'd82dfa89-81b1-449e-9ef5-cdd32957e7f3' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.`

**Spring security configuration:**

```
http.
     addFilter(headerAdminFilter).
     authorizeRequests().
     regexMatchers("/login.*").permitAll().
     regexMatchers("/api.*").fullyAuthenticated().
     regexMatchers("/jolokia.*").hasRole(ADMINISTRATOR).
     regexMatchers("/appadmin.*").hasRole(ADMINISTRATOR).
     regexMatchers(".*").fullyAuthenticated().
 and().
     formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(new RedirectingAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).
 and().
      exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
```

**HTML code for Logout button:**

```
<a id="logout-button" ng-click="ac.logout()" href="/login">Log Out</a>
```

**AngularJS code for logout function:**

```
this.logout = function () {
    $http.post("/logout");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when you try to login again the form login page uses the same csrf token that was generated previously instead of creating a new token. The old token becomes invalid when you performed logout.

Comment: I have checked the `csrf` token before and after logging out. They are different. Only strange thing that I observed is, before the login page is displayed it gets redirected to the different URL and then displays the login page. Not sure if that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following javascript snippet fixes stale CSRF token. The idea is to fetch a fresh token when the user tries to submit the login form and update the CSRF value in the form before the form is actually submitted.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form[method=post]").submit(function(event) {
        var form = this;
        $.get("csrf-token", function(content) {
            $(form).find("input[name=_csrf]").val(content);
            form.submit();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

You need a `/csrf-token` mapping on the server side that returns the current CSRF token.